# How to fix "error: call to 'abs' is ambiguous"

Tags: c++, cmath

I'm running a simple C++ program from HackerRank about pointers and it works fine on the website. However,
when I run it on MacOS, I get `error: call to 'abs' is ambiguous` and I'm not sure exactly what is ambiguous.

I've looked at other answers to similar issues,  but the error message tends to be `Ambiguous overload call to abs(double)`, which is not the issue I'm having, since I haven't used any doubles. I've also tried including the header files `cmath` and `math.h`, but the problem persists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

void update(int *a,int *b) {
    int num1 = *a;
    int num2 = *b;
    *a = num1 + num2;
    *b = abs(num1 - num2);
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

My issue occurs with line 8.

Comment: I don't know, but `abs` is in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Use `std::abs` and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: @melpomene since `C++17`, `std::abs` is defined in `<cmath>`. [Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs).

Comment: I get the same error when I use `std::abs` but the error disappears and the code works when I use `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: Can't reproduce with latest C++, please indicate dialect.

Comment: @SergeyA I think I'm using C++11 though I don't know how to find out.

Comment: @AkThao what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Chipster I'm using G++. `LLVM version 9.0.0` comes up when I type `g++ --version` in terminal.

Comment: @AkThao Ugh. I'm not familiar with it to tell you how to find out. But maybe someone else is. In order to help that person, could you also indicate what version of the compiler you are using?

Comment: I think I found the version. It's G++ 4.2.1.

Comment: So the bug goes away when you use C++ header files in a C++ program, but is present if you use C header files in a C++ program.  Hmmmm.

Comment: @Eljay Well you're not supposed to use the `.h` C header files in C++.

Comment: If you're on macOS and you didn't go out of your way to install GCC, `gcc` and `g++` are aliased to `clang` and `clang++`. You can get the compiler version with `clang --version`.

Comment: @zneak I get `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin` when using `clang --version`. I assume the first line is the compiler version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The full error message is:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp
test.cpp:8:10: error: call to 'abs' is ambiguous
    *b = abs(num1 - num2);
         ^~~
.../include/c++/v1/math.h:769:1: note: candidate function
abs(float __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return ::fabsf(__lcpp_x);}
^
.../include/c++/v1/math.h:769:1: note: candidate function
abs(double __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return ::fabs(__lcpp_x);}
^
.../include/c++/v1/math.h:769:1: note: candidate function
abs(long double __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return ::fabsl(__lcpp_x);}
^
1 error generated.
```

The three overloads of `abs` that you have from `<cmath>` are `abs(float)`, `abs(double)` and `abs(long double)`; it's ambiguous because you have an `int` argument and the compiler doesn't know which floating-point type to convert to.

`abs(int)` is defined in `<cstdlib>`, so `#include <cstdlib>` will resolve your problem.

If you're using Xcode, you can get more details about the error in the Issues navigator (⌘5) and clicking the triangle next to your issue.

Comment: So does that mean abs(int) is not defined in `<cmath>` and if so, why not?

Comment: @AkThao, the reasons are probably historic, as C originally did not have floating-point types. My guess is that floating-point support used to be optional, and they started by having it all in `math.h`. I can't name off the top of my head a function in math.h that doesn't mainly use floating-point types, and I can only name a handful of functions outside of it that use them.

Comment: I now have a slightly better answer: `std::abs` was only introduced in C++17. Prior to that, you had to use `std::fabs` to get a floating-point absolute value, and your same program would have complained that `abs` did not exist instead (possibly highlighting better that you were missing the correct `#include`).

Comment: Is `fabs` the same as `abs(float)`, `abs(double)` and `abs(long double)`? Also, since using `std::abs` doesn't fix my code, does that mean I'm using a version earlier than C++17? On a slightly related note, how do I check what version of C++ I'm using (typing `C++ --version` into the terminal only gives compiler information)?

Comment: `abs` and `fabs` are overloaded functions which perform different operations given different argument types. `fabs` is overloaded for all floating-point types, and `abs` is (in C++17, or as an extension in previous versions of C++) overloaded for all numeric types (integers and floating-point). Calling `abs(double)` should be the same as calling `fabs(double)`.

Comment: Regarding the C++ version you're using, I don't know if there's a very easy way to get an answer. The `__cplusplus` constant gives you a year and a month, but because platforms are allowed to define extensions, you can find yourself with C++17 capabilities in an environment that calls itself C++98, for instance. You can tell Clang that you want a specific dialect using the `--std=[...]` argument, where typical values would be `c++14`, `c++17`, or `gnu++14`, `gnu++17`. (The GNU versions include extensions defined by GCC.)

Answer (score 8):

For me, `#include <cstdlib>` didn't solve the issue, maybe because I didn't have to include anything to use `abs`. So, in case it helps someone else, with explicit casting, it worked well for me like in the next code:

```
*b = abs(int(num1 - num2));
```

Comment: It is the only solution which worked on Mac for me.

Answer (score 6):

In templated code, it may be easily overlooked that `std::abs` is not defined for unsigned types. As an example, if the following method is instantiated for an unsigned type, the compiler may rightfully complain that `std::abs` is undefined:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool areClose(const T& left, const T& right) {
    // This is bad because for unsigned T, std::abs is undefined
    // and for integral T, we compare with a float instead of
    // comparing for equality:
    return (std::abs(left - right) < 1e-7);
}

int main() {
    uint32_t vLeft = 17;
    uint32_t vRight = 18;
    std::cout << "Are the values close? " << areClose(vLeft, vRight) << std::endl;
}
```

A better definition of `areClose()` in above code, that would coincidentally also solve the problem of `std::abs()` being undefined, could look like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool areClose(const T& left, const T& right) {
    // This is better: compare all integral values for equality:
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value) {
        return (left == right);
    } else {
        return (std::abs(left - right) < 1e-7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your using C compiler you should include

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and use abs without std::.
If you use C++ compiler then you should change abs to std::abs.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I'm using a C++ compiler, but for some reason, using `std::abs` doesn't seem to make a difference. It only works when I use `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: That is weird.. I've tried two online C++ compilers and both works with just std::abs. Please look:

https://ideone.com/wls3Tp

https://onlinegdb.com/BJzbpcDZH

Comment: It could be that I'm using an older version of C++. In the comments to the above answer, zneak said that `std::abs` was only introduced in C++17 and before that, `std::fabs` had to be used. This is what I'm experiencing, `std::abs` does not work but `std::fabs` does. In the terminal, I tried to specify the dialect using `-std=c++17`, but it returned an error saying `invalid value 'c++17'`.

Comment: Using VS2019 defaults with a new C++ Windows Desktop Application. Only `#include <cstdlib>` or `#include <cmath>` gets abs for float. `stdlib.h` seems not to want to accept a float argument. :(

Answer (score -3):

I used `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` as the only include statement and it worked for me.
My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>  
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> findDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        if(n == 0 || n == 1)
            return {};
        vector<int> ans;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(nums[abs(nums[i])-1] < 0)
                ans.push_back(abs(nums[i]));
            else
                nums[abs(nums[i])-1] = -1 * nums[abs(nums[i])-1];
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h